# Can't install Xcode 5 command line tools

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line, osx-mavericks

Trying to install Command Line Tools on OSX 10.9 Mavericks so that I can install MacPorts after that. It's been a nightmare so far.

First, tried the old way: Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and download it from there. It does not appear on that list.

Then, I tried the command way:

```
xcode-select --install
```

The software update software opens up, asks me to install it, I say yes, then a message pops up telling me the software is not available:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQHNp.png

So I went to Apple Developer's website and downloaded manually the following file:

```
command_line_tools_os_x_mavericks_for_xcode__late_october_2013.dmg
```

I installed it, everything goes fine, no error messages appear. So I think: yes! finally!. But nothing has changed, it looks like nothing has been installed. MacPorts keeps not working, and when I check if CLT has been installed properly like this:

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI
```

I get this:

```
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
```

So as far as the system is concerned, no CLT has been installed.

Now I don't know what to do, I've tried everything the Internet could tell me and nothing has worked so far. I'm starting to get a little bit desperate.

Answer (score 2):

If the Xcode command line tools were installed without the rest of Xcode on Mavericks, the directory location where they are installed has changed to **/Library/Developer**. If the full Xcode application is installed, the command line tools will be embedded inside **/Applications/Xcode.app**.

For more information on this, please see this post:

[http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/xcode-command-line-tools-included-with-xcode-5-0-x-on-mavericks/](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/xcode-command-line-tools-included-with-xcode-5-0-x-on-mavericks/)

You may need to update your PATH values to include a reference for **/Library/Developer** in order for MacPorts to be able to detect the Xcode command line tools. The MacPorts wiki has a post on updating the PATH values for your shell profile that may help here:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#RequirementsfortheMacPortsshellenvironment

Comment: Oh, okay, so CLT comes with Xcode now. So, if I installed manually them again, do I have to remove something? Why does the checking command return nothing then? Do I have to redirect MacPorts to /Applications/Xcode.app or is it supposed to be directed there already?

Comment: Uninstalled Xcode, everything works like a charm. Wonder what'll happen when I install it back, though

Comment: @user2938976 what happened?